# iOS Capturing bigger image compared with camera preview mode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

for iPhone 6 and 6+ I used following code for stretching camera on full screen.
I basically stretch camera to full screen by using cameraViewTransform. Due to this I am getting more enlarged image compared with preview mode. How can I only capture only that part that is visible in preview mode.

Refer following screen shots for more clearance

In Iphone 6 - 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/gQNvLlr.jpg](in preview mode)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/agZmWPI.png] (captured image)

In iphone 5 - 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/odp5ZYe.jpg] (in preview mode)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/R17cE68.png] (captured image)

```
  CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            // set the aspect ratio of the camera
            float heightRatio = 4.0f / 3.0f;
            // calculate the height of the camera based on the screen width
            float cameraHeight = screenSize.width * heightRatio;
            // calculate the ratio that the camera height needs to be scaled by
            float scale = screenSize.height / cameraHeight;
            // move the controller to the center of the screen
            self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - cameraHeight) / 2.0);
            // concatenate the scale transform
            self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```